# PL SQL Trigger when update acolumn update another column in another table

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_FAC_CUS_MST_MREC_TRG   BEFORE UPDATE
   OF CUST_CODE ON fac_cus_mst   FOR EACH ROW 
     DECLARE
       v_cust_code VARCHAR2(25); 
    BEGIN
       SELECT cust_code
         INTO v_cust_code 
         FROM fac_cus_mst
        WHERE cust_code = :new.cust_code;
          UPDATE money_rec
          SET cust_code = v_cust_code
         WHERE REF = :new.REF; 
   END; 
  /
```

I tried about this code but, did it did not worked return me a error
   Like

> 10/18    PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.REF' SQL> CREATE OR
>   REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_FAC_CUS_MST_MREC_TRG   2    BEFORE UPDATE OF
>   CUST_CODE ON fac_cus_mst   3    FOR EACH ROW   4  DECLARE   5
>   v_cust_code VARCHAR2(25);   6  BEGIN   7      SELECT cust_code   8
>   INTO v_cust_code   9        FROM fac_cus_mst  10       WHERE
>   cust_code = :new.cust_code  11         UPDATE money_rec  12
>   SET cust_code = v_cust_code  13       WHERE REF = :new.REF;  14  END; 
>   15  /
>
> Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

```
SQL> show error Errors for TRIGGER UPDATE_FAC_CUS_MST_MREC_TRG:


  LINE/COL ERROR
   -------- ----------------------------------------------------------------- 4/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 8/8      PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command
   not properly ended 10/18    PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.REF'
   SQL>
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_FAC_CUS_MST_MREC_TRG   BEFORE UPDATE
   OF CUST_CODE ON fac_cus_mst   FOR EACH ROW 
    DECLARE
       v_cust_code VARCHAR2(25); BEGIN
       SELECT cust_code
         INTO v_cust_code 
         FROM fac_cus_mst
        WHERE cust_code = :new.cust_code;
          UPDATE money_rec
          SET cust_code = v_cust_code
        WHERE REF = :new.REF; 
END; 
/
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the error which you are showing, there's a problem with your Trigger. You can't write queries on the same table inside a Trigger, it will lead to ["Table is mutating"](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536903800346619276) error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_FAC_CUS_MST_MREC_TRG   
BEFORE UPDATE
   OF CUST_CODE ON fac_cus_mst  FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
          UPDATE money_rec
            SET cust_code  = :new.cust_code
         WHERE REF = :new.REF; 
   END; 
  /
```

You only need a simple update statement and refer to `:new.cust_code` directly in it.

Regarding your error `PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.REF'`, it seems that your `money_rec` table **doesn't** apparently have a **`REF`** column. Use the correct column name in its place, your Trigger should work fine.